Error fetching image: [ReferenceError: Property 'images' doesn't exist] ERROR getMyImage:
Hello,I am trying to solve a couple of errors below

getMyImage:  [ReferenceError: Property 'images' doesn't exist]  ERROR
Error fetching image:  [ReferenceError: Property 'images' doesn't
exist]  ERROR  getMyImage:  [FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object
'n6gUmMX8doMgSBYEBQuBPMmRCqI2/image.jpeg' does not exist.
(storage/object-not-found)]  LOG  書き込み開始:
https://sayhellotobike-native-ios-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com
n6gUmMX8doMgSBYEBQuBPMmRCqI2 35.52398970747676 139.4505982399833  LOG
処理を送りました。

1.I could save my image
export const saveImage = async (userData, userId) => {
  try {
    const imageUri = userData.image;
    const imageName = imageUri.split('/').pop(); // 画像名を取得
    const type = imageUri.split('.').pop(); // ファイルの種類を取得
    const mountainsRef = ref(storage, `${userId}/image`);
    const response = await fetch(imageUri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    let snapshot = await uploadBytes(mountainsRef, blob);
    console.log("Firestoreに画像情報を保存しました。",snapshot);

    // アップロードした画像のURLを取得
    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(mountainsRef);
    console.log('Download URL: ', downloadURL);

    // Firestoreに画像情報を保存
    const userDocRef = doc(firestore, `users/${userId}`);
    await setDoc(userDocRef, { imageUrl: downloadURL }, { merge: true });

    console.log("Firestoreに画像情報を保存しました。", snapshot);

  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
  } finally {
    console.log("saveImage");
  }
};





my Url is gs://sayhellotobike-native-ios.appspot.com/n6gUmMX8doMgSBYEBQuBPMmRCqI2
user_id becomes folder
the image i saved is image.jpeg
3.
i can pick up userId collectly
export const getMyImage = async (userId) => {
  try {
    const userDocRef = ref(storage,`${userId}/image.jpeg`);
  
    getDownloadURL(userDocRef).then((url) => {
    // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
    console.log("TEST",url)
    // This can be downloaded directly:
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = (event) => {
      const blob = xhr.response;
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("getMyImage: ", error);
    throw error;
  });

    return images;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("getMyImage: ", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

I hope to download from storage
thank you

None of the code you shared declares images, yet you return images;

thank you very much!I followed you and could fix it
